# Roll Back transaction support

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

Earlier we were in SSSIS 2008, we have 3 projects under a solution, Project A, Project B, Project C. I have Master Package in Project B from which I am calling packages in ProjectA and ProjectC in execute package task using external reference as File System, everything worked well till here. We recently moved from SSIS 2008 to SSIS 2012 and used Project deployment model to deploy packages to SSISDB instead of File System using Package Deployment Model, so I replaced Execute Package task with Execute SQL task in my master package to call packages from Project A and C.

I created Connection to SSISDB and used it in Execute SQL task and placed the below T-SQL code in it, it worked fine here also.

```
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution]
@package_name=N'Child_Package.dtsx',
@execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
@folder_name=N'Test',
@project_name=N'ProjectA',
@use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=Null
Select @execution_id
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]
@execution_id,
@object_type=50,
@parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
@parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
GO
```

I have 2 question here

1) If I deploy my packages from development to Production server, will this T-SQL code inside Execute SQL task works there without any issues (I read in one post that it will have some issues when deployed to diff environment) I am not hard-coding any environment parameter value inside my T-SQL code, will this work in another environment as well?

2) I am trying to implement rollback transaction support in my master package, so if any child package fails, everything needs to be rolled back, so I have Changed the package TransactionOption property to required and all other tasks(Execute SQL TASK) as supported(Default), I am ending up with an error like

"[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalo..." failed with the following error: "Cannot use SAVE TRANSACTION within a distributed transaction.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly"

The package is working fine if the TransactionOption property of the package is supported, the problem comes only when I use TransactionOption property of package as Required.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: For question 1) The package should execute just fine in another environment assuming the same version of the project is deployed and the related sprocs/tables etc. are the same between the two environments. I have used parameters to pass server name values (you already know how to set those I see in the code).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes I will be deploying the same version of the project and both the environments are similar. Is it necessary to pass server name parameter in T-SQL because in my SSISDB connection manager I am not hardcoding server name instead I am using  .(Dot) so technically it should work there also right without even passing server name.